# Having trouble with array in javascript via react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-storage

Code

```
let allurl = []
const [toReadurl, setToReadurl] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {

  
  const listRef = sRef(storage, paramKey)

  
  // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listAll(listRef)
    .then((res) => {
      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
        // All the prefixes under listRef.
        // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
      });
      res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
        // All the items under listRef.
        //console.log(itemRef)
        getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((url =>{
          //console.log(url)
          allurl.push(url)
          setToReadurl(allurl)
          //console.log(toReadurl)
          
        }))
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      console.log(error)
    });
  }, [])

    console.log(toReadurl)
```

If I put my `console.log(toReadurl)` outside the useEffect(), I get 2 items in my array only

[image]

But if I put it within the function and within useEffect(), I get 4 items in my array

[image]

Why is my array items reduced by 2 after the useEffect()?

How do I save the 4 links so I can display it out ?

Comment: since setToReadurl is asynchronous, it may not update toReadurl immediately after it is called, so if you want to access the updated state value, you may need to use the useEffect hook with toReadurl as a dependency to perform any actions that depend on the updated value.

Comment: But to display the URL I have to save the url outside the function to display them out in the app. Without saving, I cannot display it out though @HiteshPrajapati

Comment: Use a local variable to quickly obtain updated values and update the state with the new value. To access the state value, use the useEffect hook and obtain the final value when the updated value is available.

Comment: How do I do that. Currently my ```allurl``` is outside of the useEffect() function but when i tried to console.log(allurl) it contains nothing

Comment: How do I do that. Currently my allurl is outside of the useEffect() function but when i tried to console.log(allurl) it contains nothing but surprisingly I can get 2 url from ```toReadURL```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function from the `setToReadurl`. You'll receive the latest / previous values and can simply return a new array with the previous values and your new `url`.

This will allow you to remove `allUrl` and only use the state, since the `allUrl` value will be reset every render.

```js
const [toReadurl, setToReadurl] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const listRef = sRef(storage, paramKey);

  // Find all the prefixes and items.
  listAll(listRef)
    .then((res) => {
      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
        // All the prefixes under listRef.
        // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
      });
      res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
        // All the items under listRef.
        getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((url) => {
          setToReadurl((prevValues) => {
            return [...prevValues, url];
          });
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);

console.log(toReadurl);
```